# deserialize xml attribute and handle newline and other special characters

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I've tried finding the answer to this for the last 2 days and I just can't find anything that will work with our code.

We have an incoming xml response formatted as below and need to be able to handle newline and other special characters inside of attributes.

The one we're having issues with is "agent-notes" we can not seem to be able to find an XPath function to convert the special characters into \r \n etc.

"anything &#xD;&#xA;everything&#xD;&#xA;something" should be "anything \r \n everything \r \n something"

Comment: Have you looked at `Regex.Replace` and `String.Replace`? I'm not sure why you're expecting `XPath` to do character conversion

Comment: Yes, we didn't want to use Regex. Not sure why XPath isn't able to deserialize this? it is a XML parsing engine, isn't it? If we did use Regex, would you suggest we implement it in the parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunetly, you can't. The agent property value is valid and cannot be assumed to be converted for you in XPath search.  You will have to convert you search path by replacing all \n\r to "&#xD;&#xA;".  If its the value that you are expecting to be converted then you can use "HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method".

I've had this problem before and suffered the same fustration as. Coding is not always a perfect science, as much as you would like it to be.